# How do you make a kosher substitute for Beurre manié to serve with meat?

Tags: french-cuisine, kosher

Sometimes the recipe calls for Beurre manié but it includes meat as well. What is a kosher substitute for Beurre manié?

Comment: Isn't beurre manié is just butter and flour?

Comment: @Johanna yes, but butter is made from milk and is therefore unsuitable for serving with meat if you follow the Kosher laws.  Maybe the title could be tweaked though, to match the question body -- I'll suggest something

Comment: Since a beurre manié has the same ingredients as a roux (but is not cooked), the substitutes discussed in the duplicates I suggest above may help. If you think this isn't sufficient to answer your question, please [edit] to clarify :)